# Fetching facebook album of other users using graph api (javascript)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have to implement photo fetching from facebook in my website(buit in php yii2). And I have used graph api for login with fb and also fetching all albums of currently logged in user. I am getting the list if the logged in user is the owner of the app( in which the developed app using developer account). Otherwise getting null array. Is there any restriction to this request? The following is my code,

```
FB.api('/me/albums', function(resp) {console.log(resp);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about "Login Review" in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Most permissions (like `user_photos`) need to get reviewed by Facebook before they can be used by everyone.